# problem involving prime numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

If p is prime and $a^2-b^2=p$

Then solve for a and b.

In observing the equation, 1.I found a and b must be co prime.
Since p is odd,not both $ a^2$ & $b^2$ is even
And I found some example of a,b which solve the given equation.

Example a=2,b=3.

But I can't know how to solve it .please tell me from where I will start to solve it .

Note: this problem is in chapter of GCD and LCM.

THANKS.

Comment: Note that $a-b=1$ and substitute this into your equation.

Comment: Try to factorize and use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: Wow nice hint .thanks@Nilan

Comment: @Nilan But how can I prove that for every such a&b ,a-b is 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, so if $(a+b)$ and $(a-b)$ are both greater than 1 (essentially, if $(a-b)>1$), then $p$ would be composite. Therefore, we need $a-b=1$, so $a=b+1$. Now substituting this back in to our original equation, we end up with $(b+1)^2-b^2=p$, so we see that $2b+1=p$. From this, we can come up with a valid pair of (a,b) for every prime $p>2$. We see that $b=\frac{p-1}{2}$ and $a=\frac{p+1}{2}$.

Comment: I would argue that this holds for $p=2$ as well, since it was not specified that $a$ or $b$ are integers.

Comment: Yep, that's a good point.

Comment: Could you please explain how p would be composite if (a+b) &(a-b) are both greater than 1?

Comment: A number is composite if it has at least one factor other than 1 and itself. Therefore, if $(a-b)$ is greater than 1 (assuming b is not negative, then $(a+b)$ is also greater than 1), then $(a-b)$ and $(a+b)$ will both divide $p$, so $p$ is composite.

Comment: @SathasivamK a composite number by definition can be expressed as the product of factors (not equal to $1$). A composite number is the opposite of a prime.

Comment: I think my brain won't work lol

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)=p$. If $a>b>0$ are positive integers then $a+b>a-b$ are integer factors of $p$. This means that there is only one possibility $a-b=1$ and $a+b=p$, that is $a=(p+1)/2$ and $b=(p-1)/2$ for any prime $p>2$ (when $p=2$ then $a$ and $b$ are not integers, on the other hand $p$ is odd for $p>2$).